# When using AysncSession from sqlalchemy , how do I write unittests and mock the async session?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest, python-unittest

I was using alchemy_mock , but then realized that my functions were not using await and now I am completely stuck on how to do this. here is an example of code I am looking to write a unittest for.

```
from .models import User
from .exceptions import UserNameError
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy import select


async def create(db: AsyncSession, username: str, password: str) -> User:

    db_user = User(username=username, hashed_password=password)

    try:
        db.add(db_user)
        await db.commit()
        return db_user
    except IntegrityError:
        raise UserNameError(name=username)


async def get_user_by_username(db: AsyncSession, username: str) -> User:
    stmt = select(User).where(User.username == username)
    result = await db.execute(stmt)
    return result.scalars().first()
```